# How can I set the location of a stylesheet with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I set the location of a stylesheet with jQuery?

Comment: Please clarify. You can't replace files in jquery, but you can change stylesheet includes to point to a different stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate the `<head>` element in much the same way that you can elements inside the `<body>` tag:

```
$("head>link[href$=mystyle.css]").remove();
$('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/anotherstyle.css"/>').appendTo("head");
```

This removes the `mystyle.css` `<link>` tag and insert a new `<link>` tag with `/css/anotherstyle.css` at the end of the `<head>` element.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to give the `<link>` element an ID and use that as your selector, changing the `href` property on the matching element:

```
$("#myStyle")[0].href = "/path/to/new.css";
```

Another approach is to have multiple style sheets attached to your document and enable/disable them when necessary:

```
<link id="style1" href="style1.css" />
<link id="style2" href="style2.css" disabled="disabled" />
```

```
$("#style1").attr("disabled", true).next().attr("disabled", false);
```

This approach is best when regularly switching all the styles for your page.